# Cannot return manipulated data from two different queries

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, async-await

I am trying to build an express based API.

To my endpoint I want to return an array of objects. This array should created by manipulating data comming from several mysql queries.

I realize that I am missing some fundamentals here, but I am hoping for some help.
My code below is my best shot, but maybe I am doing it all wrong?

I have this router:
`app.post("/availabilities/getdayavailabilities", availability.getDayAvailabilities);`

I have this controller:

```
const Availability = require("../models/availabilitydates.model.js");

exports.getDayAvailabilities = (req, res) => {
 Availability.getDayAvailabilities(req.body.profileid, req.body.startdate, req.body.enddate, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      if (err.kind === "not_found") {
        res.status(404).send({
          message: `didn't find any dates.`
        });
      } else {
        res.status(500).send({
          message: "Error retrieving dates"
        });
      }
    } else res.send(data);
  });
};
```

And I have this model:

````
Availability.getDayAvailabilities = async (profileid, startdate, enddate, result) => {
  sql1(profileid, startdate, enddate, result);
};

function sql1(profileid, startdate, enddate, result){
  sql.query(`SELECT * FROM availabilities WHERE Profile_ID = ${profileid} AND DATE(StartTime) >= '${startdate}' AND DATE(FinishTime) <= '${enddate}'`, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: ", err);
      result(err, null);
      return;
    }
  
    if (res.length) {
      //console.log("found customer: ", res);
      sql2(profileid, startdate, enddate, res, result)
    }

    //not found Customer with the id
    result({ kind: "not_found" }, null);
  });
}

function sql2(profileid, startdate, enddate, Availabilities, result){
  sql.query(`SELECT * FROM availabilitytemplates WHERE Profile_ID = ${profileid};`, (err2, res2) => {
    if (err2) {
      console.log("error: ", err2);
      result(err2, null);
      return;
    }
  
    if (res2.length) {
      //console.log("found customer: ", res);
      createArray(startdate, enddate, res2, Availabilities);
      return ;
    }

    // not found Customer with the id
    result({ kind: "not_found" }, null);
  });
}

function createArray(StartDate, EndDate, TemplateEntries, Availabilities) {

/*
do some more stuff to the two arrays, and finally create a Newarray
*/

console.log(Newarray);
return Availabilities
}

When running this code, I can console.log my NewArray, and it looks as it should, but it is just not returned when I am calling the endpoint.

I made another endpoint which is just spitting data directly from a query that worked fine, using a model where the last parameter is a ```result```, and then in query function using```(err, res)``` as the callback function. In this simple one, the data was returned to my api using ```result(null, res[0])``` inside the query function but in the above example, I haven't been able to get working.

So how do I make two queries, wait for the response, run functions on the two responses, and finally return my final array.
````

Comment: At least I recommend to create a service function that wrap `sql.query` with callback into async function using `new Promise`

Comment: Thank you @Anatoly, your recommendation led me down the right path, and now I made it work!